# Как показать в Navigation Drawer другую активность?

Tags: java, android

Вот шаблон NavigationDrawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно реализовать показ другой активности и переключение между ними?

Comment: Вы не знаете как запустить другую активити (`startActivity(this, ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME.class);`)? При чём тут Drawer?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб суть в том, чтобы при запуске новой активити, меню Navigation Drawer продолжало работать

Comment: А почему оно у вас не работает-то ?.. Может вы просто забыли его в другой активити сделать?...

Comment: Использовать фрагменты, например.

Comment: никак у вас не получится. Используйте фрагменты.

Comment: Вот отличная инструкция как использовать фрагменты, недавно сам по ней делал: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ Там вместо Navigation Drawer используется ListView в качестве меню, однако инструкция по самим фрагментам подойдет и Вам

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать Activiti с контейнером для фрагмента и NavigationView для отображения бокового меню. При нажатии на элемент меню в контейнер подставляется нужный фрагмент с разметкой и получается как бы полноценный экран. При этом подходе не надо дублировать разметку для NavigationView и вся логика работы с ним остается в Activity.